# What is the best practice to convert network IPs in Pyspark within dataframe?

Tags: pyspark

Since, all IP addresses may not be of equal size (e.g., 10.220.50.51, 192.168.1.1),
I want to make all values before/after each dot of equal size (size = 3) by adding leading zeroes. Then remove all the dots (`.`) and concatenate each byte of the IP address together as shown below:

```
10.220.50.51 → 010.220.050.051 → 010220050051
```

I tried [StringIndexer](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#stringindexer) but couldn't manage to get right outputs.
expected output:

```
+------------+--------------+
|IP          |new IP        |
+------------+--------------+
|10.220.50.51|010220050051  |
|2.2.2.4     |002002002004  |
|192.168.1.1 |192168100100  |
+------------+--------------+
```

Comment: Before doing so, I want to ask, are you aware `10.220.50.51` is not actually same as `010.220.050.051`?  https://superuser.com/questions/857603/are-ip-addresses-with-and-without-leading-zeroes-the-same   (just to be sure that you are mapping to different _IP_)

Comment: Thanks for your input but based on your [reference](https://superuser.com/a/857618) they are mostly the same. My aim is find the alternative way to encode IP which is counted as categorical feature into numerical. Although there is something like 
*IP to Long IP Converter* but i want something straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach using higher order functions in pyspark:

```
df.selectExpr("array_join(transform(split(IP, '[.]'), x -> lpad(x, 3, '0')), '') as IP")
```

---

```
+------------+
|          IP|
+------------+
|010220050051|
|002002002004|
|192168001001|
+------------+
```